# How to write such equation as a legend in a figure?

Tags: plotting, text

The equation I want to write is

[image]

I want to put it at the upper right corner of a figure. How to write it using **Text**?

Comment: `t == Subscript[T, r] - 1` should do it

Comment: Can you be more specific? If you type it into Mathematica, it returns True.

Comment: Probably, it returns `True` because you already have told Mathematica that `t = Subscript[T, r] - 1`.  Try `Clear[t]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @bbgodfrey suggested, Try this:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2}, 
Epilog -> Inset[Clear[t]; t == Subscript[T, r] - 1, {Right, Top}, {Right, Top}]]
```